How to fixed th IP on GKE cluster
I am currently deploying a service in GKE, and I need to connect to a third-party API. This third-party API has mandatory IP filtering. I am rookie on GCloud and I do not know what exactly should do in this case.
I only created a GKE cluster and reserved an external IP address that I used within the LoadBalancer in the service, but it turns out that the IP using is the one from the Node where the pod is set.
Any recommendations?
Thanks.
